# Check if an array has different elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check if an array contains differents values :
For example i need to get true when elements are different:

```
["tata", "titi", "titi", "toto"] ==> true
```

and false when all elemnts are the same :

```
["tata", "tata", "tata", "tata"] ==> false
```

Can you tell me a way to do this

Comment: What about: ["tete", "toto", "tete", "toto"] ?

Comment: `false` i guess.

Comment: true, if just one element is different then i want it to return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `some` and `every` functions on the Array prototype.

```js
var allTheSame   = ["tata", "tata", "tata", "tata"];
var allDifferent = ["tata", "titi", "titi", "toto"];

function areAllTheSame(arr) {
  return arr.every((item, index, array) => item === array[0]);
}

function areAllDifferent(arr) {
  return arr.some((item, index, array) => item !== array[0]);
}

console.log(areAllTheSame(allDifferent));   // false
console.log(areAllDifferent(allDifferent)); // true

console.log(areAllTheSame(allTheSame));     // true
console.log(areAllDifferent(allTheSame));   // false
```

Comment: I don't think he needs to check if **all** are different but +1 for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object for this.

```
(new Set(["tata", "tata", "tata", "tata"])).size !== 1 // false
(new Set(["tata", "titi", "titi", "toto"])).size !== 1 // true
```

Wrap the login in its own method.

```
function hasUniqItems(collection) {
    return (new Set(collection)).size === 1;
}

console.log(hasUniqItems(["tata", "tata", "tata", "tata"])); // true
console.log(hasUniqItems(["tata", "titi", "titi", "toto"])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique array elements. If unique elements length is not equal(less) to actual array then it is not unique array

```
function is_unique(items){
   if(items.length  <=1 ){
       return true;
   }
   return new Set(items).size != 1;;
}
var items =["tata", "titi","titi", "toto"];
console.log(is_unique(items)); //returns true

var items =["tata", "tata", "tata", "tata"];
console.log(is_unique(items)); //returns false
```

Comment: `Set` has `.size` method. So why do you convert it to array back again?